# how can I improve this java method that takes an array of doubles and makes a conversion from kilograms to pounds and prints a bi dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to improve this method because I use break to interrupt the code otherwise it will print the array 3 times. I belive it works, but think that there must be a better way to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
//this method takes an array of doubles and returns a bidimensional array
public static double[][] allKgToPounds(double... kilogramValues) {
    double[][] result = new double[kilogramValues.length][kilogramValues.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < result[0].length;) {
            System.out.printf("[%.2f kgs-> ", kilogramValues[j]);
            result[j][i] = kilogramValues[j] * kilogramToPounds;
            System.out.printf("%.2f lbs] %n",result[j][i]);
            break;//I use break because otherwise it will print the bidemsional array 3 times
        }
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I miss understanding your code, It prints it three times because you have three columns in a row, what is the problem and why you using 2 dimensional array in case you want to print just 1 value

Comment: instead of `break` return ?

Comment: why do you need a 2D array, in my mind it makes sense to return double[] containing the converted weight. This would be in line with printing the array once?

Comment: It's for an exercise, the teacher wants a bi dimensional array that prints the kilograms and pounds like this [1kg - 2.20lbs]

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Ask yourself what is supposed to be put in the 2D array.  It makes no sense now

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you don't want an *n X n* result when given *n* kilogram values.  You want an *n X 2* result; result[*n*][0] would have the original kilogram value from kilogramValues[*n*], result[*n*][1] would have the value of kilogramValues[*n*] converted to pounds.